# How to Display photos from NSDocumentDirectory

Tags: iphone, ios

I'm developing this application on an iPad.

These codes for a 'Browse' button allows the user to view the photos from the iPad's gallery.

Code:

```
- (IBAction) BrowsePhoto:(id)sender
    {
    UIImagePickerController *imagePickerController = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
    imagePickerController.delegate = self;
    imagePickerController.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary;
    UIPopoverController *popover = [[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:imagePickerController];
    [popover setPopoverContentSize:CGSizeMake(320,320)];
    [popover presentPopoverFromRect:CGRectMake(200,200,-100,-100) inView:self.view permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionAny animated:YES];
    self.popoverController = popover;
    [imagePickerController  release];
    }

When a photo is selected, it will be stored into the application using NSDocumentDirectory.

Code:
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingImage:(UIImage *)selectedImage editingInfo:(NSDictionary *)editingInfo
    {
    [self.popoverController dismissPopoverAnimated:YES];
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDir = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *savedImagePath = [documentsDir stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"SavedImage.png"];
    UIImage *image = imageView.image;
    NSData *imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image);
    [imageData writeToFile:savedImagePath atomically:NO];
    }
```

Now i have to include a 'Display' button on the first screen.
When tapped on the button, it will show a new view (modal view controller) and displays all the photos in thumbnails/tableview from the NSDocumentDirectory.

When a photo is selected, it will be deleted from the NSDocumentDirectory.

How can i do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To Delete any file in NSDocumentDirectory in iPhone, U can use this code,

```
NSArray *sysPaths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES );
NSString *docDirectory = [sysPaths objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *filePath2 = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@", docDirectory,@"SavedImage.png"];
NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
BOOL exist =[fileManager fileExistsAtPath:filePath2];
if(exist)
  [fileManager removeItemAtPath:filePath2 error:NULL];
```